# WebChromeClient cannot be cast to org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient

Tags: java, android, cordova

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.zo.sample.$SampleWebChromeClient cannot be cast to org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient
>               at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.setWebChromeClient(CordovaWebView.java:332)

In the below mentioned part in cordova version 3.7.2

```
sWebChromeClient = new SampleWebChromeClient();
sWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
```

Comment: and what is your question ?

Comment: you need to extend s org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.setWebChromeClient to SampleWebChromeClient class.

Comment: @Niko @Krishna V I am extending the SampleWebChromeClient class with WebChromeClient as Shown below

`SampeWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient` and I am trying to set the WebChomeClient as below 

 `sWebChromeClient = new SampleWebChromeClient();
sWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);`

and I am getting above mentioned Class cast exception

Comment: @Anbu are you fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have Solved this issue as extending  the CordovaChromeClient

```
SampleWebChromeClient extends CordovaChromeClient
```

This Solved this issue the ClassCastException